# How to generate characters with a specified length?

Tags: java

I would like to generate length of characters 'z' from 1 to 99. It should be a random length of 'z' in every (40) loop. I would like to use ArrayDeque for this. I think that it should be a loop for where it will be 40 objects.
Do you have any idea how to start coding this?

I start coding. I have created a loop for. I have to create length of 'z' between 1 and 99. How to add a code where I generate random length of 'z' for this code below?

```
class loopExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayDeque<String> storeQueue = new ArrayDeque<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 99; i++) {
            storeQueue.add(i);
            System.out.println(storeQueue.size());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you clarify which part is causing a problem? Do you know how to generate a random number? Why do you want to use an ArrayDeque? What do you want the result to be - a string? A `char[]`? something else?

Comment: just use a loop and a StringBuilder. No idea why you would need a ArrayDeque for something so simple

Comment: please post, what you have tried and where your problem is, then someone can help.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @John Skeet - so I would like to generate a random length of 'z' but the length should be between 1 and 99.  I would like to put this to ArrayDeque.

Comment: @ggame you've merely restated your question there. It will be easier to answer if you provide the requested clarification.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278603/how-to-generate-string-of-char-with-only-one-type-of-letter/61279381#61279381

Comment: [I have found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278603/how-to-generate-string-of-char-with-only-one-type-of-letter/61279381#61279381) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278603/how-to-generate-string-of-char-with-only-one-type-of-letter/61279381#61279381

Answer (score 0):

```
  ArrayDeque<String> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    int randomNum = new Random().nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    deque.add(new String(new char[randomNum]).replace("\0", "Z"));

  }
```

Comment: @CodeSccale - there is an error: cannot find symbol symbol: variable IntStream location: class loopExample,
Btw I want to use for loop to generate Xtimes the 'z' charakter.

Comment: You probably run with a jdk older than 8

Comment: Check now please

Comment: It has to be 40 loops where in every loop it will be random characters of 'z' it will be random number between 1 and 99. In your piece of code is random loops. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: In Every loop you get a random number of z ...just replace the hardcoded value of 99 to 40

Comment: I have changed to 40 but there is an error : variable i is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[]),  It is a problem with variable i

Comment: Fixed. Sorry but I don't recompile each time the code

Comment: Yes, I have found this. I had to changed from i to j for the second loop for. If I run code I see only numbers but there should be strings made from 'z' for example 'zzzzz' etc.

Comment: what do you want is something like this ? --> ["zzz", "zzzzzzzzz", "z", "zz"....]

Comment: That's right. I have checked now but there is a error: cannot find symbol symbol: method repeat(int) location: class

Comment: I have checked but I can't display these strings. For every 40 loops I can't display random strings with only 'z' characters.

Comment: Not display.. strings are persist in the deque as you wish...

Comment: I can check the size System.out.println(deque.size()); but how can I display what is in the deque? I have to see something like this for example: 'z' ENTER 'zzzz' ENTER 'zzzzzz' etc.

Comment: what about this System.out.println(deque);` it will use the Deque `toString())` and you'll see the content

Comment: It is the problem because if I wanna compile your piece of code I can't it takes too much time and it is not compiled. 

Even if I add tihs code below:

 public String toString(){ 
  return deque; 
 }

Can you compile your code?

Comment: sorry but this code compiles.....which version of java do you use ?

Comment: I am trying to compile https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php



public class loopExample {
     
     public static void main(String[] args) {


ArrayDeque<String> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    int randomNum = new Random().nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    deque.add(new String(new char[randomNum]).replace("\0", "Z"));
        System.out.println(deque);
  }}}

Comment: your code compiles ...  you probably forgot to add imports in the online compiler....S

Comment: don't forget this -> ```import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Random;``` ;-)

Comment: It doesn't work anyway:

import java.util.ArrayDeque; 
import java.util.Random;
 
 
 class loopExample {
     
     public static void main(String[] args) {


ArrayDeque<String> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    int randomNum = new Random().nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    deque.add(new String(new char[randomNum]).replace("\0", "Z"));
        System.out.println(deque);
  }}}

Comment: I just try it on the online compiler... and sorry but your code works with java 8.. just decrease 99 to 2 for example otherwise it is too slow to execute. So this ```import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Random;
public class loopExample { public static void main(String[] args) { ArrayDeque<String> deque = new ArrayDeque<>(); for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { int randomNum = new Random().nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1; deque.add(new String(new char[randomNum]).replace("\0", "Z")); System.out.println(deque); }}}
```

Comment: Yes it works now but it doesn't work how it should work.
In the every loop there should be only one string with 'z'character between 1 to 99 length.
This code works that in the first loop we have one string 'zzzzz'.
In the second loop we have two strings created from 'z', in the third loop we have three strings, etc.
In the every loop it should be ony one string made from random character 'z'.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, if I understand your intent correctly, you want to make the number of loops a random value. So, very simply, I replace the upper limit `99` in your code by a variable `count` with a randomly generated value between 1 and 99. Additionally, I start looping at `0` else you might end up with zero characters in the output.

Is that what you need?

```
public class LoopRandom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 1 + new Random().nextInt(99);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.print('z');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to display this in console but in your code I see only one loop not every loops with random 'z'.

Comment: @ggame What would an example output of length 5 be?

Comment: @NomadMaker It has to be 40 loops where in every loop it will be random characters of 'z' it will be random number between 1 and 99. In your piece of code is random loops. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: In other words, you want 40 strings of random length, all composed only of the character 'z'?

Comment: Why do you want to use an ArrayDeque? You can use one, but it might be easier just to use either an array or an ArrayList.

Comment: I need to use this one.